# priority-web-sdk: startSubForm return the parent form

Tags: subform, priority-web-sdk

The following code starts a form and a subform, the issue is the I get the subForm instance of the parent:

```
    await actions.loginTest();
    const form = await actions.priority.formStart(this.formName, 
    onShowMessgeFunc, onUpdateFieldsFunc);
    console.log("form", form);
    if(form.subForms["SHIPTO2"]) {
      const subForm = await form.startSubForm("SHIPTO2");
      console.log("subform", subForm);
      subForm.choose("CUSTDES", '').then(options => {
        let custOptions = options.SearchLine.map(x => {return 
       {label:x.retval + " - " + x.string1, value: x.retval }});
        this.setState({
          customersShippingOptions: custOptions,
        })
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("CHOOSE ERROR", err);
      })
    }
```

Output:

Answer (score 2):

In order to start a subform there must be an active row in the parent form, so the subform will start for that row.

Before you start the subform you should use the [`getRows()`](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#getRows) function to retrieve rows and then call [`setActiveRow(rowIndex)`](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#setActiveRow) to set an active row. Then you could start the subform.

Modify your code to the following:

```
await actions.loginTest();
const form = await actions.priority.formStart(this.formName, 
             onShowMessgeFunc, onUpdateFieldsFunc);
console.log("form", form);
const rows = await form.getRows();
await setActiveRow(5);
if(form.subForms["SHIPTO2"]) {
   const subForm = await form.startSubForm("SHIPTO2");
   console.log("subform", subForm);
   ...
}
```

By the way: I see you're using [`choose()`](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#choose), Here too there needs to be an active (subform) row,use `getRows()` with `setActiveRow()` or create a [`newRow()`](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#newRow) before calling `choose()`

Comment: thanks, I am looking for the right order of actions to update field. I tried several ways to update field, mostly what happens that I am updating the same fields multiple times and I am getting the following error: "This record already exists in the screen" . after I start form and setActiveRow(1) I am doing  fieldUpdate and then saveRow(1), I am also added getRows() but I don't think it is needed. any suggestions?

Comment: better if you open a separate question for this, and post your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52034074/priority-web-sdk-fieldupdate-for-choose-field-failed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pull the first line on the screen more than just use the `autoRetrieveFirstRows` parameter
In the function `formStart`

[Link to the function on the Web SDK site](http://Hey%20If%20you%20want%20to%20pull%20the%20first%20line%20on%20the%20screen%20more%20than%20just%20use%20the%20autoRetrieveFirstRows%20parameter%20In%20the%20function%20formStart%20https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/global/#formStart)

I personally define this value as default