# priority-web-sdk: fieldUpdate for choose field failed

Tags: priority-web-sdk

My form contains a field with drop down values (the values came from the choose function) and when I am trying to update the field (with fieldUpdate) in the second time I always get the following error: "A record with the same value already exists in the screen", What is the correct order of actions that need to be done in order to achieve the right behaviour? 
This is my attempt to achieve that:

```
await actions.loginTest();
const form = await actions.priority.formStart(this.formName, 
this.onShowMessgeFunc, this.onUpdateFieldsFunc);
_formInstance = form;
const rows = await form.getRows(1);
console.log("parent form rows", rows);
await _formInstance.setActiveRow(1);
form.choose("CUSTNAME", '').then(options => {
let custOptions = options.SearchLine.map(x => {return {label:x.retval + " - 
" + x.string1, value: x.retval }});     
}).catch((err) => {
console.log("CHOOSE ERROR", err);
})
```

When I select a value from the drop-down, those are my actions:

```
await _formInstance.fieldUpdate("CUSTNAME", data.value);
await _formInstance.saveRow(1);
const rows = await _formInstance.getRows(1);
console.log("rows", rows);
```

In the first time it work's great, but when I select a different value for the second time I get an error that say that this value already exists (it's like it think that I am trying to update the value but I don't, I just want to get the values of other fields that return as a result of the field trigger when I leave the field in Priority). I don't have any purpose to change values, just getting information on other fields and data from sub-forms.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have any purpose to change values, just getting information on other fields and data from sub-forms.

In order to achieve your purpose you could choose one of the following flows, that should work:

1. **Recommended**: Use `getRows()` after you have [`setSearchFilter()`](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#setSearchFilter) in order to retrieve the row you're interested in including its fields. Then easily `setActiveRow()` with its index to `startSubForm()`. You could always use [`clearRows()`](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#clearRows) to clear the current rows and retrieve others.

   Example:

   ```
   const form = await actions.priority.formStart(this.formName, 
                this.onShowMessgeFunc, this.onUpdateFieldsFunc);
   const filter = {
     QueryValues:
     [{
       field: 'CUSTNAME',
      fromval: value,
      op: '='
    }]
   }
   await form.setSearchFilter(filter)
   const rows = await form.getRows(1);
   console.log("parent form rows", rows);
   await form.setActiveRow(1);
   await form.startSubForm(1);
   ```
2. Perform the 'update' on a `newRow()` without calling `getRows()`. Then `saveRow()` and `startSubForm()` to get the information you need. Do this for each record you trying to retrieve its data.

   Explanation: When calling `getRows()` you retrieve some rows. Then you cannot update a `key` field with a value that already exists in the retrieved rows otherwise you get that error.

Comment: does the REST API contain functionality like the 'choose' function in the WEB SDK?

Comment: let me try to rephrase my question, what is the quick and fast way to fill dropdown field like I mention above (CUSTNAME)? does I need do to the following: formStart, getRows(), setActiveRow(1), and then form.choose('CUSTNAME', '')? it just for preparing the screen and it takes a lot of time, then after I select the customer name, the trigger of the field return me values of other fields, I don't need to prepare filter for searching it, it already came from the trigger (onFieldUpdateCallback). I need the minimal mandatory actions for doing that

Comment: @Dvirbenishay I guess it takes a lot of time because you are still using getRows() without setting a filter (its like querying '*'). Either use getRows() with a filter or use newRow() instead, as I have already suggested. By the way, what version of Priority you are using?

Comment: our Priority version is 18.2.0.24. our critical issues with the web-sdk is basically performance, it takes much more time to prepare screen with 'choose' field and even more time when you want to prepare subform with 'choose' field, your documentation doesn't give you enough details about the order of actions that you need to do in order to achieve the best performance (most of the times I just use the REST API because it faster), but still 'choose' field (not supported in REST API) has some logic inside and it forces me to use the web-SDK and it decrease the UX of my website.